# Conditional Operators using SQL Connection Object

Tags: c#, operators

From this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) article I assume that this:

```
protected SqlConnection _connection;

if (_connection != null)
{
    _connection.Dispose();
    _connection = null;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
protected SqlConnection _connection;
_connection?.Dispose();
_connection = null;
```

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Dispose() will be invoked only if _connection != null in both cases

Comment: But you shouldn't be doing that.  You should create the `SqlConnection` in a `using` block at the point you use it, not storing it as a class member as your code seems to be doing.  You shouldn't reuse them.

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs and recommendations.